# forbid custom php config settings on apache 2.2 + mod_php server

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-php

I have a server where php is running as an apache module.

Every user on the server is restricted to his own directory with open_basedir.

I have disabled the following functions:

disable_functions = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source

Now I'd like to forbid custom php config settings, such as:

memory_limit

max_execution_time

max_input_time

post_max_size

upload_max_filesize

How would you go about it?

ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `php_admin_value` and `php_admin_flag` directives to hard code the values into your apache config, this will prevent both `.htaccess` and `ini_set` from overriding the values you set.

You can read about these directives in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

Comment: Ah! Thanks SubOracle, I read that page but missed the "Any directive type set with php_admin_value can not be overridden by .htaccess or ini_set()". Do you reckon this will still be true even if there is "AllowOverride all" in my httpd.conf? Well I'll make a test myself asap and report back.

Comment: php_admin_value memory_limit 128M worked even with AllowOverride All